# How to provide a test period within non-renewing subscriptions in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Good day,

I faced with an interesting problem:

I provide 1, 3, 5 and 7-days free test period for an application, according to the task, that user have done. For example, if a person first authorized through fb account, he has test week to try full functionality.

The problem is that I:

1. Can't do it without in-app purchase (11.1, 11.2)
2. Can't use subscription for less than a week (11.6: Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices)
3. Can't use non-renewing subscription without money

Can you propose, what type of in-app purchase should I use?

Comment: Why does this need to be an in-app purchase at all?  You say it's free, just save the time when the app is first run and use that to decide what features to enable.

Comment: Lewis, thank you for the answer, originally I did like what you say. I did it without in-app purchase. But now I try to submit a new version and I get a reject because of 11.1 (Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected), so your doesn't suit me.

Comment: That seems strange.  How do you unlock the full functionality after the free trial?

Comment: No, I unlock full functionality only after user's premium-account buying. Test period is only to try.